# Error "Compiling transformation: '<invalid-global-code>.Host.get' ..." in a T4 template

Tags: c#, t4

I started getting this error in a T4 template I use fairly regularly but just started modifying.

```
Compiling transformation: '<invalid-global-code>.Host.get' is a new virtual member in sealed class '<invalid-global-code>'
```

It wasn't happening before I started changing things around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was because of two things...

- I was using an include file that had a syntax error (that I had just introduced) which made it fail to compile properly
- I had misplaced the starting/ending (`<#`, `#>`) blocks in part of the tt file I was working on.

The combination of these two things made VS report the somewhat useless error mentioned in the title. I found the syntax error by copying the include file contents into a regular class file. Once that was fixed VS was able to give me a better focused error message about the incorrect starting/ending blocks.